# Asp.net dynamic controls from l2e

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

G'day, I have an aspx page that has its html stored in a sql server 2008 table which uses linq to entities to retrieve & display in a placeholder on the page. This all displays correctly except for an asp button that will not display. Viewing the source of the page shows that the button is there but it is not on the page.

`Page = Page.Replace("!LOGINBUTTON!", "< asp:Button id='login' text='Login' runat='server' />")`

How do I get it to display?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever code you are replacing with !LOGINBUTTON! is .ASPX code. It is not a pure HTML to display button.
When ASP.net actually render page asp:Button Converted with HTML `<Input Type="Button" .....` with appropriate Javascript functions(for postback).

In this case if you want to see button with its postback event you need to write

```
Page = Page.Replace("!LOGINBUTTON!", "&lt; intput type='Button' id='login' text='Login'/&gt;")
```

I hope it will work.